# Handling ascii char in python string

Tags: python, ascii, decode, asciiencoding

i have file having name `"SSE-Künden, SSE-Händler.pdf"` which having those two `unicode char ( ü,ä)`  when i am printing this file name on python interpreter the unicode values are getting converted into respective ascii value i guess `'SSE-K\x81nden, SSE-H\x84ndler.pdf'` but i want to

test dir contains the pdf file of name 'SSE-Künden, SSE-Händler.pdf'

i tried this:
    path = 'C:\test'
    for a,b,c in os.walk(path):
        print c

```
['SSE-K\x81nden, SSE-H\x84ndler.pdf']
```

how do i convert this ascii chars to its respective unicode vals and i want to show the original name(`"SSE-Künden, SSE-Händler.pdf"`) on interpreter and also writeing into some file as it is.how do i achive this. I am using Python 2.6 and windows OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your terminal session's character encoding set to UTF-8?

Comment: sorry but how to verify that.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, Terminal (from the menu) --> Set Character Encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your terminal supports displaying the characters, iterate over the list of files and print them individually (or use Python 3, which displays Unicode in lists):

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> for p,d,f in os.walk(u'.'):
...  for n in f:
...   print n
...
SSE-Künden, SSE-Händler.pdf
```

Also note I used a Unicode string (u'.') for the path.  This instructs `os.walk` to return Unicode strings as opposed to byte strings.  When dealing with non-ASCII filenames this is a good idea.

In Python 3 strings are Unicode by default and non-ASCII characters are displayed to the user instead of displayed as escape codes:

```
Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 10 2011, 21:51:15) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> for p,d,f in os.walk('.'):
...  print(f)
...
['SSE-Künden, SSE-Händler.pdf']
```

Comment: sorry i didnt mention before i am using python 2.6 and windows os, ipython

Comment: His question is how to display the unicode characters in their native form (non-byte format)

Comment: +1 Using a unicode path does indeed work, interesting and non-obvious.

Comment: no i tried on python 2.6.7 i am getting following error:UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x81' in position 22: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Shashi, interesting.  Your filename is a Unicode string but contains the cp437 (US Windows console encoding) character value for ü.  Was this file originally created on Windows?  I created the file for the example above and the Unicode characters for ü and ä are `\xfc` and `\xe4`.

Comment: No i am not sure..whether is is crated on windows or not.OK for my side Unicode characters for ü and ä are \x81 and \x84 ...

Comment: @Shashi: Does the filename display correctly in Windows Explorer?

Comment: I tried this filename.encode("mbcs") then it skips the ascii ('\x81','\x84') values .means it shows the string like "SSE-Knden, SSE-Hndler.pdf" its changing his meaning.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3686/discussion-between-mark-tolonen-and-shashi)

Answer (score 1):

```
for a,b,c in os.walk(path):
    for n in c:
        print n.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: +1: This should work if his terminal session is set to display unicode.

Comment: To set the windows terminal to unicode see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console

Comment: This won't work if the file system doesn't use UTF-8, such as Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For writing to a file: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data